# Why is the if statement invalid syntax?

Tags: python, if-statement

If I try to run my code, I get the error:

```
File "main.py", line 80
    if Tut_Ans2 == ('Approve'):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import time
import random
Lives = 5

print ("Hello new recruit, welcome to the bank of \n")
time.sleep (0)

print ("A new law was just passed yesterday.\n")
time.sleep (0)

print ("Now all cheques must be approved by the writer.\n")
time.sleep (0)

print ("You will need to write Approve if they yeet.")
time.sleep (0)
print ("Or Deny if they don't yeet\n")

time.sleep (0)

print ("Oh look, our first customer, I'll show you how to do it.\n")
time.sleep (0)

print ("Okay, so here's the cheque that this person has just given to us.\n")
print (" ")
print (" ______________________________")
print ("|    29/09/06                  |")
print ("|  From: Cristian Western      |")
print ("|  To: Charlotte Webb   £1200  |")
print ("|    Age: 37     Gender: F     |")
print ("|      Bank of Sandle-land     |")
print ("|______________________________|")
time.sleep (0)
print (" ")
print ("And heres the approval cheque from the writer.")
print ("")
print (" ______________________________")
print ("|    29/09/06                  |")
print ("|  From: Cristian Western      |")
print ("|  To: Charlotte Webb   £1200  |")
print ("|    Age: 37     Gender: F     |")
print ("|      Bank of Sandle-land     |")
print ("|______________________________|")
time.sleep (0)
print (" ")
Tut_Ans = input(str("Everything matches up, so now you need to type Approve to approve this cheque.\n"))

if Tut_Ans == ('Approve'):
 print ("Good job!\n")
elif Tut_Ans == ('approve'):
 print ("Good Job!\n")
elif Tut_Ans == ('deny'):
 Lives = Lives - 1
 print ("No, these match up.\n")
elif Tut_Ans == ('Deny'):
  Lives = Lives - 1
  print (("You now have ") + str(Lives) + (" failures left until you're fired!\n"))
elif Tut_Ans != ('approve') or ('Approve') or ('Deny') or ('deny'):
  print ("No, you must type approve or deny.")

print ("Here comes another customer.\n")
print ("I'll show you again.\n")
print (" ______________________________")
print ("|    29/09/06                  |")
print ("|  From: Cristian Western      |")
print ("|  To: Charlotte Webb   £1200  |")
print ("|    Age: 37     Gender: F     |")
print ("|      Bank of Sandle-land     |")
print ("|______________________________|\n")
print ("And heres the approval cheque from the writer.\n")
print ("_______________________________")
print ("|    28/7/17                   |")
print ("|     From: Christian Western  |")
print ("|     To: Charlotte Web  £9000 |")
print ("|     Age: 92      Gender: M   |")
print ("|       Bank of Palm tree      |")
print ("|______________________________|/n")
print ("")
Tut_Ans2 = input(str(print("Guess you have to write Deny!"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just try

```
Tut_Ans2 = input("Guess you have to write Deny!")
```

instead of

```
Tut_Ans2 = input(str(print("Guess you have to write Deny!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three `(` and only two `)` :

```
 Tut_Ans2 = input(str(print("Guess you have to write Deny!"))
```